# Help with the proof of Theorem 1 (Chapter 2) of Suppes' "Axiomatic Set Theory"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic

See the proof of

> **Theorem 1** : $x \notin 0$

[page 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8KjB.png) and [page 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0OJM.png).

Anybody can help me with the first step of the proof.

I don't understand why the author uses in this step "x belongs to empty set" and "x not equal to x".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [theorem to be proved](https://books.google.it/books?id=sxr4LrgJGeAC&pg=PA21) is :

> $x \notin \emptyset$.

The author uses the [Axiom schema of separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) ( top page 21, slightly modifying the letters used ) :

> $(\exists A)(\forall x)(x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B \land \varphi(x))$.

The author consider the instance of the axiom schema with $\emptyset$ as $B$ and where formula $\varphi(x)$ is $(x \ne x)$.

The result is the formula :

> $(\exists A)(\forall x)(x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in \emptyset \land (x \ne x))$.

Thus, using the *Separation axiom* we have proved that a set $A$ such that ... exists.

Now, consider what happens for an $x$ whatever such that $x \in A$.

From : $x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in \emptyset \land (x \ne x)$ we have : $x \in \emptyset \land (x \ne x)$ and then in turn :

> $(x \ne x)$.

But this is impossible (because $(\forall x)(x=x)$ is an [equlity axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms)) and thus we have to conclude that our assumption : $x \in A$, leads to a contradiction.

This means that we are forced to conclude with :

> $x \notin A$,

and from the fact that $x$ is an object whatever, that :

> > $(\forall x)(x \notin A)$.

Now we have to use **Definition 1** (page 19) stating that an object

> $y \text { is a set iff } (\exists x) (x \in y) \lor (y = \emptyset)$

and apply it to set $A$.

$(\forall x)(x \notin A)$ is equivalent to $\lnot (\exists x) (x \in A)$, and thus, by [Disjunctive Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism) :

> > $A = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. Only in the first line you have made a errata: you put "x≠∅" in place of "x∉0", but it is a minor issue. The fact is that you resolved my question. And the key was your line: "Thus, using the Separation axiom we have proved that a set AA such that ... exists." It was the point that I didn't catch. Thank you very much. –