# Theorem 1 in Suppes's Axiomatic Set Theory - why is the empty set used?

Tags: set-theory

A question was recently asked about Theorem 1 of Suppes's axiomatic set theory [asking why the empty set was used](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158120/help-with-the-proof-of-theorem-1-chapter-2-of-suppes-axiomatic-set-theory/3158156#3158156?newreg=35809840cb8442608add4e87cde2a0fa). I have a related question. Why, in the formula:

$(\exists{C})(\forall{x})(x \in C \iff x \in \emptyset \& (x \ne x))$

does Suppes use the empty set as the set of which $A$ is a subset? That is, wouldn't the theorem be equally valid if he had made this first line:

$(\exists{C})(\forall{x})(x \in C \iff x \in B \& (x \ne x))$

In other words, isn't the superset irrelevant (it can be $B$, $\emptyset$ or any other set) if ultimately what we are proving is that no $x$ can be a member of $A$ because x≠x is absurd?

Comment: I think you're right: with $\varphi(x) =(x\ne x)$, $B$ can indeed be taken any specific set.

Comment: If you want to use a different set than $\emptyset$, you'll have to prove that your set exists, which is unnecessary work.

Comment: Why would you have to prove that the set exists? For example, in a later proof in the same chapter, he writes $(\exists{C})(\forall{x})(x \in C \iff x \in A \& x \in B)$. Here he does not prove the existance of $A$ (or $B$ for that matter).

Comment: Suppes is using capital variables as abbreviations for variables that are constrained to be sets. (@NateEldredge Suppes is axiomatizing ZFA here). A full statement of the separation instance would be "if $B$ is a set then there is a set $C$ such that for all objects $x,$ $x\in C$ if and only if $x\ne x$ and $x\in B.$" Thus you need to prove $B$ is a set in order to infer that $\forall x (x\notin C).$ The easiest way to do this is to substitute a term that can be proven to be a set. (On the other hand I don't see an axiom that says "$0$ is a set"... which as far as I can tell is an oversight.)

Comment: @Mike For your example, when you prove this statement you *assume* that $A$ and $B$ exist (Free variables in formulas refer to things that exist... what else could they refer to?) And more substantially, since they are capital letters, you assume they are sets.

Comment: Thanks, @spaceisdarkgreen. I think I'm getting it. The second comment makes intuitive sense, but what I still don't get is "you need to prove $B$ is a set in order to infer that $\forall{x}(x \notin C)$". Maybe it is too subtle, but I don't understand why $B$ cannot be assumed to exist in the first example (meaning you need to prove it exists) but _can_ be assumed to exist in another.

Comment: @Mike This is subtle. In most formulations of set theory, all objects are sets, so "$B$ exists" and "$B$ is a set" mean the same thing. But Suppes allows urelements, so even if an object exists, it is not necessarily a set. In his convention, capital letters are always implicitly sets, and separation as stated would be wrong without this additional assumption. Whether we're allowed to "assume $B$ exists" depends on whether the underlying logic or other axioms imply the universe is nonempty. Here, since we have a constant symbol, it is, but we need something stronger, namely that a set exists.

Comment: @Mike (Actually, I take back what I said about there being an oversight before. Definition 1, the definition of the set predicate, implies that 0 is a set, so the axiom I thought was missing is not, and we can prove $0$ is a set and hence that a set exists. And to clarify, once you have the existence of a set, you can instantiate an arbitrary set and sub it for $B$. Or you can sub $0$, a term which we know is a set, for $B$. Either way is fine, as long as you're subbing a set.)

Answer (score 1):

At this stage in the development of the theory, no sets have been defined except the empty set, (whose existence is posited as a primitive constant of the theory).  It is the only primitive formula involving set that can be used in the axiom schema of separation.